# Can't generate correlated random numbers from binomial distributions in R using rmvbin

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to get a sample of correlated random numbers from binomial distributions in R. I tried to use rmvbin and it worked fine with some probabilities:

```
> rmvbin(100, margprob = c(0.1,0.1), bincorr=0.5*diag(2)+0.5)
```

while the next call which is quite similar one raises an error:

```
> rmvbin(100, margprob = c(0.01,0.01), bincorr=0.5*diag(2)+0.5)
  Error in commonprob2sigma(commonprob, simulvals) :
    Extrapolation occurred ... margprob and commonprob not compatible?
```

I can't find any justification for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a math/stats "problem" and not an R problem (In the sense that it's not a problem but a consequence of the model)

Short version: For bivariate binary data there is a link between the marginal probabilities and the correlation that can be observed. You can see it if you do a bit of boring juggling with the marginal probabilities $p_A$ and $p_B$ and the simultaneous probability $p_{AB}$. In other words: the marginal probabilities put restrictions on range of allowed correlations (and vice versa), and you are violating this in your call.

For bivariate Gaussian random variables the marginals and the correlations are  separate and can be specified independently of each other.

The question should probably be moved to stats exchange.